# When does (1.0/x)*x - 1.0 not evalute to 0.0?

Tags: java

I'm searching for an example when the expression

```
(1.0/x)*x - 1.0
```

does not evaluate to 0.0, assuming that x is a double value in Java.

I'm also interested in a reason for that.

Comment: x = 0.  Homework?

Comment: I'd say it's not true for any value of x that cannot be expressed exactly in binary.  Obligatory: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Testing floating point numbers for equality is generally a no-no due to precision losses on the CPU level. Code that does so is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Joe not accurate. I tried it with 0.333333333 and 2.3 and both times returned true.

Comment: Im sorry, but now my question is changed. It's not in the correct form anymore. I'll do a rollback.

Comment: `(1.0/x)*x - 1.0` never evaluates to true

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the values of `x` which end up cause floating point arithmetic to give imprecise results is VM-vendor-dependent... But anyhow, I suppose it probably is more likely to happen with values with a lot of decimal places.

Comment: @Romain: It's not vendor dependant at all, at least if you specify strictfp - that's why there's the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: For future reference: **equations** have **equals** signs in them. Hence various editors' confusion over what you actually meant...

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt does the Java standard actually state that the VM has to implement IEEE 754 standard floating point numbers? If so then you're right, it's not vendor-dependent. If not, then you can have a vendor that thinks they're smarter than the IEEE... And provide creepy stuff...

Comment: @Romain: Yes, the Java standard definitely specifies that floats are IEEE 754, except it allows implementations to use an extended exponent range for intermediate values in classes or methods that are not declared strictfp.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Right, so it's IEEE754 or "better", so definitely vendor-independent for the bulk of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a program that will list all values for which this is the case.

```
public static final void main(String[] args){
    for(long i=Long.MIN_VALUE; i<Long.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(i);
        if(0.0d != (1.0d/d)*d - 1.0d){
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Turns out there's lots and lots and lots of them - the program starts with a large range of denormalized numbers, and it's the case for all of them.

To get numbers in a more familiar range:

```
public static final void main(String[] args){
    for(long i=Double.doubleToLongBits(1.0d); i<Long.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(i);
        if(0.0d != (1.0d/d)*d - 1.0d){
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Still lots and lots of hits.

The reason? `double` has limited precision, and therefore it's fundamentally unable to represent all numbers. If your calculation has an intermediate result that cannot be exactly represented by  `double`, your algebraic equalities cannot be expected to hold.

Answer (score 7):

Some obvious examples include:

- `x = 0.0`
- `x = Double.NaN`
- `x = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`
- `x = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`

Less obvious examples:

- `x = 0x1p-1050` (a [denormalized double](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM05-J.+Do+not+use+denormalized+numbers))
- `x = -1.0 / Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` ([negative zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero))

There may be examples where there occurs loss of precision, but I am yet to find one.

Answer (score 2):

```
double x = 0.2300000000000001;
System.out.println((1.0/x)*x - 1.0);
```

Floating point loses precision.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? This evaluates to `true` on my JVM.

Comment: Sorry, somebody has changed my question, so that it isn't true anymore.

Comment: I used groovy. Reason is still the same. Updated the code to reflect the new question and a value that actual fails

Answer (score 0):

`x == 0`

Because 0*infinity is undefined in maths.

Answer (score -1):

I would try x = square root of 2 as it is none rational number and cannot be expressed as floating. for all who suggests x == 0, this is illegal equation. he is searching for a leagal value.

found an example, x = Math.sin(4.0).